# Biblatex-chicago and bibliography compilation problem

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style, textmate

Taking all your comment into consideration this is my problem. I am writing my PhD dissertation on a Macbook using OSX Mactex2013 and textMate. Every now and then I have an issue with compiling the bibliography with bibtex. It seems that bibtex does not find the bib file as it gives the "exited with status 2" message. But this happens only once every now and then, and when it does I have to search for hours on the internet and the tex stack exchange to find possible solutions. The curious thing is that it happens without me doing nothing: for instance, it was working fine before Christmas, then I left it all for about 3 weeks. When I came back and opened my file WITHOUT ANY CHANGE IN IT, I could not make bibtex work once again. I have tried what worked before: delete the .aux files etc.; delete some strange code lines that suddenly appeared at the beginning of the document and that were creating the issue; try to change some packages. Nothing works apparently.

I've made this minimum example, and it still does not work (bibtex "exited with status 2"): the references (`\autocite` command) are not recognised and transformed into the full citation.

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\bibliography{Bibliography2.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber,hyperref=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{document}
\include{Chapters/Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Maybe you could post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: I'm afraid, as it stands now it will be very hard to answer your question. It is better to prepare a really minimal WE: get rid of all the `\include`s, load only necessary packages etc. You might want to start de-cluttering your files anyhow (the `\documentclass` call does seem to have way to much options.). It would also help to actually see the error message(s) output by LaTeX (if any)?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure which are necessary and unnecessary packages. I'll try to figure out how to make a MWE.

Comment: Apparently, I can't post a MWE because the number of characters is limited. I also cannot post as an answer because it is restricted.

Comment: Please do not use `\bibliography{Bibliography2.bib}` but `\addbibresource{Bibliography2.bib}`. Could you provide more information about the error BibTeX throws?

Comment: I tried with `\addbibresource', but it gives the same result: "Found 0 errors, and 0 warnings in 0 runs

bibtex exited with status 2" in TextMate. In TexShop: "I found no \citation commands---while reading file Thesis.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis.aux
(There were 3 error messages)"

Comment: Well, you need to run biber instead of BibTeX if you specify `backend=biber`. (You can also use `backend=bibtex` and run BibTeX).

Comment: I've tried again and now it gives the warning message: "No data sources defined!" I'm sorry if my questions are silly, but I'm a bit lost. Why was it working well before with `backend=biber`? How do I run biker instead of bibtex? I only have the bibtex option on my Latex readers.

Comment: Update: It is now working fine. I'm not sure why since I haven't done really anything much different. But I did a few things, and learned others. TextMate 2.0 does automatically recognise and run biber or bibtex. I uninstalled and reinstalled the Latex bundles. I ticked the preference box in the Latex bundle for using Latexmk.pl.